# How do I add text under the navbar

Tags: html, css, navbar

I would like to ask how the text could be added under the navbar, I tried moving the text but is there any simpler way to do it? I tried doing basic text moving, but it doesn't seem to work.

The CSS code is mostly the animation, if someone could just move the paragraphs (p)

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300&display=swap');
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #ED952D;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  background: #0F0A0A;
}

header::after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

nav {
  float: right;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 70px;
  padding-top: 23px;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
}

nav a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: white;
  transition: 3s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

nav a::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  background: grey;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 0%;
  transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}

nav a:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="logo"></h1>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="FIBA.html">FIBA</a></li>
      <li><a href="HISTORY.html">HISTORY</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<header>
  <p>start of the info</p>
</header>
```

Comment: It is not clear what you want. You have a start tag `<header>` and where do you want the text?

Comment: You need to provide more code, it ends at the opening ```<header>```.

Comment: mplungjan, i would like the text like basically under the navbar, its going to be an informative page so like to the side or something. thanks

Comment: @TimothyAlexisVass <div class="container">
      <h1 class="logo"></h1>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="FIBA.html">FIBA</a></li>
          <li><a href="HISTORY.html">HISTORY</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
</div><header>
<p>start of the info</p>

Comment: Please edit your original post instead. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300&display=swap');
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #ED952D;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
}

header {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 0 10%;
  background: #0F0A0A;
}

header::after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

nav {
  float: right;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 70px;
  padding-top: 23px;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
}

nav a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: white;
  transition: 3s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

nav a::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  background: grey;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 0%;
  transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}

nav a:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1 class="logo"></h1>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Basic</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<main>
  <p>Here is some text</p>
</main>
```

Comment: Just would like to say thank you and how do I return the navbar to the original long state? Its cropped off and if that would happen I would need to move the text to the middle, thanks

Comment: You could add padding to the header. I updated the code.

Comment: Thank you so much timothy, really helped out!!